# Delete node method not actually deleting node in binary search tree. C++

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

When I call my removeNode method, it shows to delete the node locally and set it to null in the debugger, but when I look at the tree in the debugger the node that should have been deleted is still there. When I print the tree the node that should have been deleted prints, but the int and string assigned to the struct it points to print out gibberish instead.

I've tried using free() and delete but neither actually deleted the node.

```
bool BinTree::addNode(int id, string info, DataNode *add_node) {
    auto *temp_node = new DataNode;
    temp_node->data.id = id;
    temp_node->data.information = info;
    temp_node->left = temp_node->right = nullptr;

    if(id < add_node->data.id){
        if(!add_node->left){
            add_node->left = new DataNode;
            add_node->left = temp_node;
            count++;
        }else{
            addNode(id, info, add_node->left);
        }
    }else{
        if(!add_node->right){
            add_node->right = new DataNode;
            add_node->right = temp_node;
            count++;
        }else{
            addNode(id, info, add_node->right);
        }
    }
}

bool BinTree::removeNode(int id, DataNode *temp_root) {
    cout << "Searching to remove: " << id << endl;
    if(temp_root == nullptr){
        return false;
    }
    else if(id < temp_root->data.id) {
        removeNode(id, (temp_root->left);
    }
    else if(id > temp_root->data.id){
        removeNode(id, temp_root->right);
    }
    else{
        //no child
        if(temp_root->left == nullptr && temp_root->right == nullptr){
            cout << "Deleting no children node" << endl;            //DEBUG ONLY
            cout << "Temp root address:" << temp_root << endl;      //DEBUG ONLY
            delete temp_root;
            temp_root->data.id = 123456;                            //DEBUG ONLY
            cout << "no child deleted" << endl;                     //DEBUG ONLY
            count--;
        }
        //one child
        else if(temp_root->left == nullptr){
            cout << "Deleting 1 child node" << endl;
            DataNode *temp_node = temp_root;
            temp_root = temp_root->right;
            delete temp_node;
            temp_node = nullptr;
            count--;
        }
        else if(temp_root->right == nullptr){
            cout << "Deleting 1 child node" << endl;
            DataNode *temp_node = temp_root;
            temp_root = temp_root->left;
            free(temp_node);
            temp_node = nullptr;
            count--;
        }
        //two children
        else if(temp_root->left && temp_root->right){
            cout << "Deleting 2 child node" << endl;
            DataNode temp_node = minValueNode(temp_root->right);
            temp_root->data = temp_node.data;
            removeNode(temp_node.data.id, temp_root->right);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

DataNode BinTree::minValueNode(DataNode *temp_node) {
    while(temp_node->left){
        temp_node = temp_node->left;
    }
    return *temp_node;
}
```

I have some debug output in the method to verify that the temp_root address that it is deleting is the same address that the tree has for the given node, and that is correct. It is just not deleting it from the actual tree.

Comment: `delete temp_root;
            temp_root->data.id = 123456;` is undefined behavior.  You can't use a pointer after you delete it unless you are reassigning it to another valid address.

Comment: I did that to check the output of the code and instead of gibberish it will hjave 123456 in the integer. Just used to verify that it is in fact not being deleted.

Comment: The variable `temp_node` and `temp_root` are local to the function. You did not change any nodes in the actual tree just local variables.

Comment: ***Just used to verify that it is in fact not being deleted.*** That is not a valid test. It's undefined behavior to dereference the deleted pointer.

Comment: How do I pass the actual value of root to temp_root? My impression was passing it this way would allow me to directly modify the tree.

Comment: Philosophical question. If delete node method not actually deleting node, should we still call it `delete note` method?

Comment: ***How do I pass the actual value of root to temp_root? My impression was passing it this way would allow me to directly modify the tree*** pass the pointer by reference instead of by value.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would write the remove to return the new value of a link.

```
void removeNode(int id) {
    root = removeNode(id, root);
}
Node* removeNode(int id, Node* n) {
    if (n == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    if (id < n->id) {
        n->left = removeNode(id, n->left);
        return n;
    }
    else if (n->id < id) {
        n->right = removeNode(id, n->right);
        return n;
    }
    else if (n->left == null) {
         Node* result = n->right;
         delete n;
         return result;
    }
    else if (n->right == null) {
         Node* result = n->left;
         delete n;
         return result;
    }
    else {
         int v = findSmallestValue(n->right);
         n->right = removeNode(v, n->right);
         n->id = v;
         return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where this accounts for a node with no children, I may be reading it incorrectly though.

Comment: @justenc94 you don't need that. If a node has no children then both left and right are null. It will thus be caught by `else if (n->left == null) {` which deletes the current node and returns the right node as the new node for this position. The right node is already null and so we get the correct behavior.